What is the name of this Russian Folksong
Where can I find different versions of this Russian Folksong
o the steppes
Googling 'O the Steppes" of course returns nothing.
This song is a real hit with me and I want to find out how other artists interpret it.  It appears in Pasolini's Il Vangelo Secundo Matteo around 1:37:00 which is how I found it.

Never mind, I think I found the answer.  Here's another version https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WffKp82tfyw  Still, if someone could post the lyrics and perhaps find more version that way.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Russian language or its usage

https://ru.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Ах_ты,_степь_широкая
